# In GitBash on Windows 10, how do you change the cursor from a line to a box?

Tags: windows-10, cursor, git-bash

I'm using GitBash on Windows 10.  It seems the default cursor is a line

[image]

but this is somewhat difficult to see at times.  How would I make the default cursor a filled rectangle?

Comment: The filled-rectangle cursor is the Insert cursor… which may not really be what you want.

Comment: I want anything I can see.  The thin line is not eye-catching and hard to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, open or create the file `~/.minttyrc` and add the lines

```
CursorType=block
CursorBlinks=no
```